# Taking the address of a managed object using fixed statement

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

From [MSDN - fixed statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx)

> The fixed statement prevents the garbage collector from relocating a movable variable.
>
> The fixed statement sets a pointer to a managed variable and "pins" that variable during the execution of the statement. Without fixed, pointers to movable managed variables would be of little use since garbage collection could relocate the variables unpredictably. The C# compiler only lets you assign a pointer to a managed variable in a fixed statement.

How come I am not allowed to create a pointer directly to my managed variable (example code below)?

```
using System;

class Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int xx, int yy)
    {
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("({0}, {1})", x, y);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void TestPointRef()
    {
        Point p = new Point(3, 5); // Create a new Point instance

        unsafe
        {
            fixed(Point* pp = &p) // <- This is not allowed
            {
                Console.WriteLine(*pp);
            }
        }
    }

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestPointRef();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains and says

> error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare
>   a pointer to a managed type ('Point')

I thought we are allowing ourselves to take the address of managed objects using the fixed statement? It is permissible (as in the MSDN example in the link) to declare a pointer to a value-type member in `Point p`, but not to `p` itself.

What am I missing?

Comment: The C# language strongly restricts the kind of pointers you can use, it won't permit a pointer to a managed reference type.  You'd get ahead in this specific case by declaring Point as a *struct* instead.  In which case you'll notice that *fixed* isn't required anymore either in this snippet since `p` is already in a fixed location.

Comment: @HansPassant I see, and the reason for _fixed_ not being required when Point is declared as a structure is that `p` is allocated on the stack (so not subject to GC)?

Comment: Yes, method arguments and local variables have a fixed location.  Static variables do too but C# does not know that.  You need fixed for a static, an element of a Point[] array or if the Point is field of a class.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't understand your comment... in the context of the question (which is within a `fixed` statement) saying "*The C# language [...] won't permit a pointer to a managed reference type*" seems contradictory with MSDN statement "*The C# compiler only lets you assign a pointer to a managed variable in a fixed statement*". So it seems the question has not been answered (and I'm actually trying to understand why the pointer can be set to the address of `p.x`, a value type `int` and not to the address of `p`,  a reference type `Point` (a case MSDN seems to allow too).